# Converting lowercase to uppercase in shell script

Tags: shell

I tried to convert a lowercase string to uppercase and assign it to a variable using the following code

***The script is written in .tn extension***

```
set y a12
y_up=$( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $y)
echo $y
echo $y_up
```

But I am getting the error

```
invalid command name "A-Z"
while executing
"A-Z"
invoked from within
"y_up=$( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $y) "
```

How can I convert this?

Comment: `set` does not what you think it does...

Answer (score 9):

Below Works, Try this.

```
bash-3.2$echo lower to upper | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
LOWER TO UPPER  

# To Save in the variable use below
var=$(echo lower to upper | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

Comment: Actually I am writing these in .tn script , there it is still showing the error that  :lower: command not found

Answer (score 7):

BASH 4+ version has native way to convert sting to upper case:

```
upperStr="${str^^}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$ y="Foo Bar Baz"
$ y_up=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $y)
$ echo $y_up
foo bar baz
```