# Convert lower case to upper case in tn_shell script

Tags: tcl

I have a variable defined a12. Wanted to convert this variable to upper case and assign it to another varialble

***IT IS A .tn script with the script header includer --- >   #!/bin/tn_shell***

Please help me in solving this .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `tn_shell` is a bourne like shell, you can probably do:

```
a13=$( echo "$a12" | tr a-z A-Z )
```

or

```
a13=$( echo "$a12" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] )
```

Comment: That's shell, not Tcl…

Comment: Is `tn_shell` a Tcl shell?  Googling `tn_shell` is not at all useful, but does tell me where to get petrol in Tennessee!

Comment: I've no idea, but the question _is_ tagged… (Tennessee; hmm, I've changed planes there…)

Answer (score 1):

```
a="$(tr [a-z] [A-Z] <<< "$a")"
```

---

```
bash-3.2$echo lower to upper | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
LOWER TO UPPER  

To Save in the variable use below
var=$(echo lower to upper | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746638/converting-lowercase-to-uppercase-in-shell-script)

[Like 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting)

Comment: That's shell, not Tcl…

Answer (score 0):

Madre mia. I need write this text because post's minimum is 30 characters

```
tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

Comment: That's shell, not Tcl, and doesn't actually deal with values in variables…

Answer (score 0):

To turn a string into upper case, use `string toupper`. That returns a *copy* of the input string (with the case transformation applied, of course) that you can then assign to wherever you want.

```
set a13 [string toupper $a12]
```